Testdome boat movement question fails incomprehensibly
My code is failing the (public) test on testdome. The test in question: https://www.testdome.com/library?page=1&skillArea=32&questionId=113618
I get the following:

Example case: Correct answer
All coordinates are inside the grid: Wrong answer
Some coordinates are outside the grid: Wrong answer

I check if all values in the path are set in the $gameMatrix array, including the starting and ending position.
If they are set to either true or false, it must be "within the grid" in my mind.
My code:
<?php
/**
 * @return boolean The destination is reachable or not
 */
function canTravelTo(array $gameMatrix, int $fromRow, int $fromColumn, 
                     int $toRow, int $toColumn) : bool
{
    if($fromRow == $toRow){ // Moving horizontally
        // if(abs($fromColumn - $toColumn) > 2) 
        //     return false; // Out of reach?
        $toCheck = range($fromColumn, $toColumn);
        foreach($toCheck as $col){
            if(!isset($gameMatrix[$fromRow][$col]))
                return false; // Out of bounds
            if(!$gameMatrix[$fromRow][$col])
                return false; // Path is blocked
        }
        return true;
    }elseif($fromColumn == $toColumn){ // Moving vertically
        // if(abs($fromRow - $toRow) > 2) 
        //     return false; // Out of reach?
        $toCheck = range($fromRow, $toRow);
        foreach($toCheck as $row){
            if(!isset($gameMatrix[$row][$fromColumn]))
                return false; // Out of bounds
            if(!$gameMatrix[$row][$fromColumn])
                return false; // Path is blocked
        }
        return true;
    }else{
        // Moving diagonally is not allowed
        return false;
    }
}

$gameMatrix = [
    [false, true,  true,  false, false, false],
    [true,  true,  true,  false, false, false],
    [true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true],
    [false, true,  true,  false, true,  true],
    [false, true,  true,  true,  false, true],
    [false, false, false, false, false, false],
  ];
  

echo canTravelTo($gameMatrix, 3, 2, 2, 2) ? "true\n" : "false\n"; // true, Valid move
echo canTravelTo($gameMatrix, 3, 2, 3, 4) ? "true\n" : "false\n"; // false, Can't travel through land
echo canTravelTo($gameMatrix, 3, 2, 6, 2) ? "true\n" : "false\n"; // false, Out of bounds


I have tried creating my own unit-tests with various edge-cases, but I cannot recreate the failure.
I have tried adding a maximum reach for the boat, but that did not seem to be the issue, neither is it mentioned in the documentation.
Am I missing something obvious here?

The following is passing the test.
<?php
/**
 * @return boolean The destination is reachable or not
 */
function canTravelTo(array $gameMatrix, int $fromRow, int $fromColumn, 
                     int $toRow, int $toColumn) : bool
{
    // Out of bounds
    if(
        $toRow > count($gameMatrix) - 1
        || $fromRow > count($gameMatrix) - 1
        || $toColumn > count($gameMatrix[0]) - 1
        || $fromColumn > count($gameMatrix[0]) - 1 
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Moving illegally
    if(
        // ... within the same column, up or down
        (
            $fromRow !== $toRow && abs($toRow - $fromRow) > 1
        )
        // ... within the same row, left or once/twice (at most) right
        ||
        (
            $fromColumn !== $toColumn && (
                ($fromColumn - $toColumn) > 1
                || ($toColumn - $fromColumn) > 2
            )
        ) 
    ) {
        return false;
    }
    
    if($fromRow == $toRow){ // Moving horizontally
        $toCheck = range($fromColumn, $toColumn);
        foreach($toCheck as $col){
            if(!$gameMatrix[$fromRow][$col])
                return false; // Path is blocked
        }
        return true;
    }elseif($fromColumn == $toColumn){ // Moving vertically
        $toCheck = range($fromRow, $toRow);
        foreach($toCheck as $row){
            if(!$gameMatrix[$row][$fromColumn])
                return false; // Path is blocked
        }
        return true;
    }else{
        // Moving diagonally is not allowed
        return false;
    }
}

$gameMatrix = [
    [false, true,  true,  false, false, false],
    [true,  true,  true,  false, false, false],
    [true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true],
    [false, true,  true,  false, true,  true],
    [false, true,  true,  true,  false, true],
    [false, false, false, false, false, false],
  ];
  

echo canTravelTo($gameMatrix, 3, 2, 2, 2) ? "true\n" : "false\n"; // true, Valid move
echo canTravelTo($gameMatrix, 3, 2, 3, 4) ? "true\n" : "false\n"; // false, Can't travel through land
echo canTravelTo($gameMatrix, 3, 2, 6, 2) ? "true\n" : "false\n"; // false, Out of bounds

I've removed the out-of-bounds check from within the foreach loop, and set it as the first thing to check. I'm going with the assumption that every row will have the same number of values, hence the count($gameMatrix[0]) > 1 check.
Now, the key part is the second check. Namely:
    // Moving illegally
    if(
        // ... within the same column, or down
        (
            $fromRow !== $toRow && abs($toRow - $fromRow) > 1
        )
        // ... within the same row, left or once/twice (at most) right
        ||
        (
            $fromColumn !== $toColumn && (
                ($fromColumn - $toColumn) > 1
                || ($toColumn - $fromColumn) > 2
            )
        ) 
    ) {
        return false;
    }

If you were to comment out this part, you would get failed checks. The reason for this is - if you're inside row 2, with your original code, the move from (2,0) to (2,5) would be considered legal, and it's not, at least not according to the setup:

The player controls a boat unit with a particular movement pattern. It can only move to fixed destinations from its current position as shown in the image below:



Thank you, I see what you are saying. I assumed the marked squares was just sample squares, didn't realize it could literally only move one up, down or left, and one or two right. But you know what they say about assuming.
